# Pointer variable, differences in var and &var

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int* z = new int(9);

    cout << "address: " << z << endl;
    cout << "value: " << *z << endl;
    cout << "referance: " << &z << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Looking at the cout values, I was expecting the address and reference to give the same address, but heres what the output is:

```
address: 0x7fc452c032a0
value: 9
referance: 0x7fff5191b8d8
```

Just curious about the reason for this, is the plain value(z) the address of the variable in the heap with a value of 9, where var(&z) is address of the pointer variable which is located in the stack?

Here is a visualization:

[image]

Is the

Comment: `&` in `&z` is an _address-of_ operator.

Comment: If you do `*(&z)`, it gives you `z`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me go through some of the basics first.

- A variable is a name that is used to refer to some location in the memory, a location that holds a value with which we are working.
- Using '&' in C/C++ we can get the address of the variable.
- A pointer is a variable that stores the address of a variable. For instance, in the example you are referring to

  ```
  int* z = new int(9);
  ```

  variable z stores the address of the value 9 [new int(9)].

Now, finally this variable has to be stored at some location in the memory and this can be accessed using ampersand (&).

```
    &z //gives the address of the pointer to value 9 (address of variable z).
```

This is the same way the pointers and pointers to a pointer (multi level pointers) works.

Comment: Is the int 9 stored at address z or address &z?

Comment: I would put in this way,
Address of value 9 is stored in variable Z.

    `int x = new int(9);
    int* z = &x;`

Comment: Awesome, Thanks so much! You helped big time

Answer (score 3):

`&z` designates the **adress of** the pointer `int * z` where you store the allocated adress `new int(9)`.

The pointer `z` and the value `9` are stored at two different locations in memory.

There is not any notion of *reference* here, only *adresses*.

Answer (score 1):

```
int* z;
```

Above statement implies a pointer variable of `int` type declaration.

```
int* z = new int();
```

Above statement implies an address is allocated to pointer variable of `int` type dynamically.

```
int* z = new int(9);
```

Above statement implies value `9` is stored in a dynamically allocated.

```
cout << "address: " << z << endl;
```

Above line of code tells the address of pointer variable `z`.

```
cout << "value: " << *z << endl;
```

Above line of code tells the value stored in the variable `z`.

```
cout << "referance: " << &z << endl;
```

Above line of code tells the dynamically created variable's address.